# How to alter files on external SD after 4.4 KitKat upgrade?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, sd-card

I am unable to alter files on the SDHC card since I accepted KitKat on my Samsung Galaxy Mega Plus. It is not rooted. How may I make that external SDHC read-write without esoteric things like Rooting the phone? Which file manager apps permit file moves and deletes?

Comment: What app are you using? Apps not optimized for this new security feature won't be able to read or write to the SD card

Comment: Without root: no chance. That's a so-called "safety feature" introduced by Kitkat, which you can only work-around with root, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy though you can install custom roms without rooting. But I get the point though.

Comment: @saloalv Well, kinda the same – as those "custom ROMs" usually come rooted :) But yes, some manufacturers (such as Huawei) even solved the issue in their (non-rooted) stock ROMs. Unfortunately only few did so...

Comment: @Izzy key word "usually" ;)

Comment: @saloalv: Is there a file management app which will write to the SD card? You allude to the existence of one in your first comment, may I ask if you can name one?

Comment: @K7AAY I'm pretty sure ES File manager ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) can do that

Comment: @K7AAY for me, with kitkat even the internal sdcard has different permissions now, and my device doesn't support a physical SD card, so it might be that es file manager has found a kitkat internal sdcard workaround, but not an external one.

Comment: Nope. ES File Manager did not permit writing or deletion.